# Is it possible to add a play inside a play that will use copy module on a define host vi ansible?

Tags: ansible

Hi I have a playbook that fetch information from remote server and place it local server, is it possible to add a play that will copy that file in local and place it on a specific host? I plan to code it below or you have any recommendation what would be best approach? although the server 1 is not in the inventory file that the playbook used.

```
- name: Get compliance reporting from remote
  fetch:
  src: /tmp/compliancereporting.out
  dest: /home/ansible/linuxpatchingv2/OUTGOING-COMPLIANCE_v2/inventory_{{ '%y%m%d%H%M%S' | strftime }}
  flat: yes

- name: Copy the fetch file
  host: server1
  copy:
  src: /home/ansible/linuxpatchingv2/OUTGOING-COMPLIANCE_v2/inventory_*
  dst: /tmp/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [fetch module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html) will copy the file(s) from remote host to Ansible control machine at `<dest>/ansible_hostname`.

E.g. for `host1.example.co` and `dest: /home/ansible/linuxpatchingv2`:

```
/home/ansible/linuxpatchingv2/host1.example.co/tmp/compliancereporting.out
```

So in your playbook, you will have two plays. First play will `fetch` the file to Ansible control machine, second will `copy` the file fetched in first play to remote machine.

```yaml
- name: Fetch the file from host1.example.co
  hosts: host1.example.co

  tasks:
  - name: Fetch the file
    fetch:
      src: /tmp/compliancereporting.out
      dest: /home/ansible/linuxpatchingv2/

- name: Copy the file to remote host server1
  hosts: server1

  tasks:
  - name: Copy report to remote path
    copy:
      src: /home/ansible/linuxpatchingv2/host1.example.co/tmp/compliancereporting.out
      dest: /tmp/
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the fetch part is working with inventory have different servers, I'm just trying to add the copy play in my existing play but the copy play will use a specif host. also Im using roles, cause when I try you solution I'm getting below: "ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path."

Comment: You cannot have `hosts:` in a role tasks file. Perhaps you can update the question on how you are using the role. Also you should have all hosts that you want to target, in your inventory - and have copy to remote as a play task rather than role.